# Bootstrap 3 thumbnail displaying content outside thumbnail

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have an issue with my thumbnail on Bootstrap 3.

I have a thumbnail within this thumbnail I display a header, image and below the image two columns to display content in a list form. As demonstrated below;

[image: image1]

However; my code is displaying the lists below the thumbnail as seen here;

[image: image2]

I cant seem to move the lists into the thumbnail and I cant think why.

Here is the code is question

```
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                     <h4 align="center">Landscaping & Ground Work</h4>
                         <img src="/images/icons/garden.png" alt="Landscaping & Ground Work">

                         <div ="row">
                              <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-6">
                                   <ul class="">
                                       <li>test</li>
                                       <li>test</li>
                                   </ul>
                              </div>
                              <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-6">
                                   <ul class="">
                                       <li>test</li>
                                       <li>test</li>
                                   </ul>
                              </div>
                         </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by adding `<div style="display:block;clear:both"></div>` after i closed the row div and before i close the thumbnail div.

and changing `<div ="row"> to <div class="row">`

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                     <h4 align="center">Landscaping & Ground Work</h4>
                         <img src="/images/icons/garden.png" alt="Landscaping & Ground Work">

                         <div ="row">
                              <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-6">
                                   <ul class="">
                                       <li>test</li>
                                       <li>test</li>
                                   </ul>
                              </div>
                              <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-6">
                                   <ul class="">
                                       <li>test</li>
                                       <li>test</li>
                                   </ul>
                              </div>
                         </div>
                    <div style="display:block;clear:both"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Would you mind accepting your own answer so other people with the similar problem can effectively use your answer?